# Use Placeholder with % sign in string.xml for String.format()

Tags: java, android, xml, string, string-formatting

I am Using placeholder %1$d in string.xml for `int` value, and then I want to display `%` sign in same `TextView` so it's `&#37;`. So I've use it like this.

```
<string name="uploadProgress">%1$d&#37;<string>
```

Now in Java Code I used it like this.

```
int progress = 10;
textView.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.uploadProgress), progress));
```

But it is showing:

> java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion:

I Tried with:

1. `%` instead of `&#37;`
2. Put a Space between `%1$d` and `&#37;`(But I don't want space
   actually.)

But no luck. How can I achieve this? I've looked another SO questions for solution but I'm not able to find particular one.

Comment: Did you try `\u0025` in place of `&#37;`?

Comment: Android doesn't use the &# syntax.  Like Bob said, use \u

Comment: Also have a look at [`getString(int, Object...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int,%20java.lang.Object...))

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've run into this as well. There are two ways to escape a literal percent symbol in XML string resources.

For your case (a string with parameters, e.g. `%1$d`) you should use `%%` to escape the percent symbol literal.

If your string does not have parameters, then you should use `\u0025` to escape the literal percent symbol.

If you use `%%`in a string without parameters, then `getString()` will resolve it as a literal `%%` instead of escaping it. If you use `\u0025` in a string *with* parameters, then `getString()` will crash trying to treat that `%` as a format parameter.

Answer (score 2):

If your string resource have no parameters, then you can use formatted="false" attribute.

In your case you need to use double-%

Comment: I can Only Upvote Your Answer It's absolutely right. But the answer which @kcoppock Gave It's more specific & Descriptive which can help other also in Future and the SO aim also will be achieve. Thanks For Giving Right Andswer

Comment: That is fair enough. :)